# google chart with proportional X-axis

Tags: google-visualization

I am new with Google chart.
I am wondering If I can do the following:
Assuming the X-axis shows date. If I have 3 values, one for the 1st of december, one for the second, and one for the 10th of december. Is it possible to have the X-axis showing all dates between the 2nd of december and the 10th of december even if I didn't provide any values for those dates? the curve going from the value of the 2nd to the value of the 10th. THe goal is to have something linear, without jump in the time.
A workaround might be that I provide those dates with "null", but I would like to prevent this, if google chart can handle it.

thanks,
Rod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.  You just need to enter your dates in a "date" type column as Date objects (instead of strings in a "string" type column).